# We have a multifield with rte and have used JSON_STORE. We are facing an issue of href getting removed when dialog is saved for the second time

Tags: aem

We have a multifield with rte and have used JSON_STORE. We are facing an issue of href getting removed when dialog is saved for the second time. First time the href value is retained but second time it’s removed. Making the storage NODE_STORE resolves the issue but it’s a time consuming process since there are many live pages using the component. Anyone has any other solution for this.

Comment: Please try escaping the url for href or use a texfield in the dialog instead of a url.

Comment: Which version of AEM is this? Have you migrated the component to coralUI3 from 2? As I've seen this issue before when using coral2 and upgrading to coral3 had resolved this issue.